# Cannot get accepts_nested_attributes to work in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

This might be a case of me being blind… 
Somehow I cannot get my layout_positions_attributes to arrive at layout_positions

```
l = Layout.new
…
[17] pry(main)> l.layout_positions
=> []
[18] pry(main)> l.layout_positions_attributes=[{:name=>'xxx'}]
=> [{:name=>"xxx"}]
[19] pry(main)> l.layout_positions
=> [] # WTF!
[20] pry(main)> l.layout_positions.build({:name=>'xxx'})
=> #<LayoutPosition id: nil, name: "xxx", active: true, columns: nil, rows: nil, layout_id: nil, pos: -1>
[21] pry(main)> l.layout_positions
=> [#<LayoutPosition id: nil, name: "xxx", active: true, columns: nil, rows: nil, layout_id: nil, pos: −1>]
```

The parent class:

```
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :active, :layout_positions_attributes
  has_many :layout_positions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :layout_positions,
                                :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? },
                                :allow_destroy => true
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

And where the attributes should go…

```
class LayoutPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :active, :columns, :rows, :pos
  belongs_to :layout
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling it to reject it if the `content` for the `layout_position` object is blank. In your example, above "WTF", you're not passing through any content. Therefore this is deleting the attributes.

Calling `build` doesn't rely on `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and so will work just fine.